# How to set the image on top of the div as constant

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have an image with the pattern on the right. I wanted to be it always on the top of the div. My current implementation is making the image move and repeat it whenever the browser is resized.
Below is my fiddle attached.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="pattern-top"></div>
        <div>Hello World!</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fcbe07;
  padding: 25px 15px;
  margin-top:30px;
}

.pattern-top {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/NsQ3tXg/Corner-cover.png") repeat-x 0 0;
  top: -25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: switch 2 divs under container (put Hello World first). z-index may help as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the below properties to the `.pattern-top` class

```
background-position: right 100px top;
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped!